# 404 calling asmx when just upgraded to .net 4

Tags: .net, asmx

I've just upgraded a .NET 2 ASMX web service to .NET 4.

The pre-upgraded version of the web service runs fine on our IIS 7 web server in a .NET 2 classic app pool.

Changing the app pool to .NET 4 classic causes it to give a 404 error. This happens regardless of whether I put the new .NET 4 binaries for the web service in place.

I can't find any clues in the event audit.

I suspect the issue is to do with handler mappings but whenever I try to add these, I get a 500 error.

My web.config is very simple currently - and just contains appsettings.

The .NET 4 compiled version of the web service runs fine in vshost in development.

Hope someone can give me some clues.

Comment: You do have the .NET 4.0 web service extension set to allowed in IIS, right?

Comment: No... but I do now and it's working perfectly. Thank you :-)